# Why is MergeSort in Haskell faster when implemented with foldl'?

Tags: haskell, mergesort, fold

I have implemented two versions of Merge Sort in Haskell like follows:

```
mergeSort1 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort1 xs = foldl' (\acc x -> merge [x] acc) [] xs
```

and

```
mergeSort2 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort2 [] = []
mergeSort2 (x:[]) = [x]
mergeSort2 xs = (mergeSort2 $ fst halves) `merge` (mergeSort2 $ snd halves)
         where halves = splitList xs
```

where 'merge' and 'splitList' are implemented as follows:

```
merge :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge [] [] = []
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge all_x@(x:xs) all_y@(y:ys)
     | x < y = x:merge xs all_y
     | otherwise = y:merge all_x ys

splitList :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitList zs = go zs [] [] where
     go [] xs ys = (xs, ys)
     go [x] xs ys = (x:xs, ys)
     go (x:y:zs) xs ys = go zs (x:xs) (y:ys)
```

Doing `last $ mergeSort2 [1000000,999999..0]` in ghci results in showing the number 1000000 after more than a minute of processing, while doing `last $ mergeSort1 [1000000,999999..0]` results in showing the last element only after 5 seconds.

I can understand why mergeSort1 uses much less memory than mergeSort2 because of the tail-recursiveness of foldl' and so.

What I can't understand is why mergeSort1 is faster than mergeSort2 by such a big difference ?

Could it be that splitList is the bottleneck in mergeSort2, generating two new lists every call?

Comment: Don't test these things using ghci; it's not at all representative of a compiled program's performance.  Compile test programs with optimization (`-O`); you can use [`criterion`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion/) to benchmark it, or if you want to be quick and dirty, just write two separate test programs and use the Unix `time` utility to time them.

Comment: @sacundim Yes I have tested them both in executable format, compiled with -O2 and still the difference is big. mergeSort1 finishes in 4 seconds, while mergeSort2 58 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<del>As is,</del>

```
mergeSort2 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort2 xs = (mergeSort2 $ fst halves) `merge` (mergeSort2 $ snd halves)
         where halves = splitList xs
```

<del>is an infinite recursion, since you haven't given a base case (you need to specify the result for lists of length `< 2`)</del>. After that is fixed, `mergeSort2` is still relatively slow due to the `splitList` which requires a complete traversal in each step and builds two new lists, not allowing to process anything before that is completed. A simple

```
splitList zs = splitAt h zs where h = length zs `quot` 2
```

does much better.

Your `mergeSort1`, however, is not a merge sort at all, it is an insertion sort.

```
mergeSort1 :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
mergeSort1 xs = foldl' (\acc x -> merge [x] acc) [] xs
```

That does particularly well on reverse-sorted input, but if you give it sorted or random input, it scales quadratically.

So `mergeSort1` was faster because you gave it optimal input, where it finishes in linear time.

Comment: sorry, forgot to paste the 2 lines of base case for mergeSort2. Now they are edited there.

Comment: Okay, the remainder of the answer is unaffected, `mergeSort1` isn't a merge sort, and your input was optimal for that insertion sort.

Comment: Tried it with your implementation of splitList and also with sorted input, and still mergeSort1 performs at least 5 times faster than mergeSort2 in every test, with the performance gap widening with every 10x increase of N.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong but I think the best case for insertion sort is when the input is already sorted where it scales linearly.

Comment: That is entirely contrary to my findings. `last $ mergeSort1 [1 .. 8000]` takes 3.13 seconds, for `mergeSort2` (with my `splitList`), 0.02 seconds. And whether sorted or reverse-sorted is the good case for an insertion sort depends on whether you're using a left fold or a right fold. For the left fold, reverse-sorted is the good one.

Comment: You're right. I was mistakengly testing with a version of merge sort written with foldr, and hence the best results for sorted input. My correct testings are the same as yours now. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: `splitList` still requires a complete traversal of the list, and still requires *one* new list to be generated, so I'm not sure if your explanation is complete.

Comment: @BenMillwood: I think splitList isn't the bottleneck here. In mergeSort1 'merge' gets called N times for every element of the list, while in mergeSort2 it is called log2N times. For reverse sorted input, mergeSort1 had the best case performing linearly, because merge recursed only 1 time, while for random or sorted input, recursive calls to merge increase to the number of elements N, thus scaling quadratically and performing slower than mergeSort2 for a great number of elements.

Comment: @tonlika: well, fair enough, but the answer suggests that the performance of `splitList` is significant, so if that's not true then the answer is misleading.

Comment: @BenMillwood: actually from my tests splitList implemented with splitAt is more than 2 times faster then my splitList version. But the main point was that I was using optimal input for mergeSort1, and I was seeing performance ratios of 1:50 in comparison to mergeSort2.

Comment: Yeah, so that suggests to me that the first half of this answer is a little bit of a red herring, that's all.